# filter on a many_to_many field

Tags: django, django-views

new to django, this might be a simple/obvious question, so I apologise in advance.

I have the following model

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="members", blank=True, null=True)
```

And the following view (controller)

```
def my_teams(request):
    my_list = Team.objects.filter(???????).order_by('name')
    return render_to_response('teams/index.html', {'my_list': my_list})
```

The objective of this view is to list only those project which the current logged in user is a member of. Being a many to many relationship there can be many members in each team.

Any advice on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't describe the `Project` model but I guess it has a foreign to the `Team` one. So here is how I would to that :

```
Project.objects.filter(team__user=request.user).order_by('name')
```

Comment: sorry Project should have read Team in the view code - now fixed. Is this answer still valid?

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation on the answer above as I made a slight mistake copying my code across

```
my_list = Team.objects.filter(members=request.user).order_by('name')
```

Thanks for your help!